# Include path being ignored in a gnu make file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The makefile is included below.  It's just a long list of object files and two targets.  The problem seems to be that the $(INC) is being ignored for the first target.  For example, the output starts with "g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp" instead of "g++ -I/usr/home/jrm/tmp/proteus_beta -c -o main.o main.cpp".

TIA

```
PROG = proteus

# list of object files
OBJS = main.o \
dataset.o \
genetic_codes.o \
likelihood_engine.o \
options.o \
parsimony.o \
parsimony_engine.o \
seq.o \
site_collection.o \
site_pattern.o \
tools.o \
optare/crs.o \
optare/point.o \
optare/newton_1d.o \
optare/golden_section.o \
models/model.o \
models/DNA/DNA_model.o \
models/DNA/DNA_ssm.o \
models/CODON/CODON_model.o \
models/CODON/CODON_modelA.o \
models/CODON/CODON_modelB.o \
models/CODON/CODON_modelC.o \
models/CODON/CODON_modelD.o \
models/CODON/CODON_M0.o \
models/CODON/CODON_M1.o \
models/CODON/CODON_M2.o \
models/CODON/CODON_M3.o \
models/CODON/CODON_M0gtr.o \
models/CODON/CODON_FEBC1.o \
models/CODON/CODON_FEBC1b.o \
models/CODON/FESC/CODON_FESC1.o \
models/CODON/CODON_nh/CODON_M0nh1.0 \
models/CODON/CODON_nh/CODON_M1nh1.0 \
models/CODON/CODON_nh/CODON_M1nh1.0 \
models/CODON/CODON_nh/CODON_M3nh1.0 \
models/CODON/CODON_nh/CODON_M0nh2.0 \
models/CODON/CODON_nh/CODON_MmodelAnh2.0 \
matrices/matrix.o \
matrices/DNA_matrix.o \
matrices/CODON_matrix.o \
matrices/AA_matrix.o \
matrices/int_matrix.o \
matrices/str_matrix.o \
matrices/eigen.o \
incidere/slice_sampler.o \
dendrology/forestry.o \
dendrology/node.o \
dendrology/DNA_node.o \
dendrology/tree.o \
alphabetia/alphabet.o \
alphabetia/DNA_alphabet.o \
alphabetia/CODON_alphabet.o \
alphabetia/AA_alphabet.o

CC = g++

INC=-I/home/jrm/tmp/proteus_beta

.C.o:
 $(CC) $< -c $(INC)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
 $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) -lm
```

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your post, you have a file named `main.cpp`, not a file named `main.C`.  But you provide an implicit rule for converting `.C` files to `.o`.  Make will compile `main.cpp` using its built-in rule for `.cpp` to `.o` compilation.  You have two options to do what you want:

(1) Change your implicit rule to `.cpp.o` (and consider using new-style rules, i.e. `%.cpp: %.o`)

(2) Declare a `CXXFLAGS` variable (which is automatically included in Make's C++ compilation implicit rule) such as the following:

```
CXXFLAGS = $(INC)
```

and then remove your `.C.o` implicit rule.

The second option will simplify your makefile, and it will work with C++ files, regardless of the extension.

Comment: All the source extensions end in .cpp and .h, but the .C.o rule does seem to find all the .cpp files.  I think I remember it has a special meaning (finds *.c *.cpp and some others).  But, I did take your advice and followed suggestion 2 and now the objects all build.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do your source files end with `.C` or `.cpp`?

The compilation rule for `.C.o` lists `$(INC)` after the other parts of the rule, not where you expect the output to come:

```
CC  = g++
INC = -I/home/jrm/tmp/proteus_beta

.C.o:
    $(CC) $< -c $(INC)
```

You should see:

```
g++ file.C -c -I/home/jrm/tmp/proteus_beta
```

But it appears to be ignoring your rule altogether.  You mention `main.cpp`; that will never be compiled by your rule.

So, is `.C` a recognized suffix?  Are your source files `.C` files?  Are you running on a case-insensitive file-system?  Why are you setting the C compiler (CC) -- you've probably got case problems with your source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  See my comments above.